# Meteor: sending the document id via email

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a newsletter which relies on meteor's email package.

As soon as an admin submits a new *news & events* entry to the collection, all subscribers receive this via email. This also works.

However, I want to have add the new concrete link of the news & events entry to the page.

The route for the news and events page:

```
// Specific news and events
Router.route('/news-and-events/:_id', {
    name: 'newsAndEventsPage',
    waitOn: function(){
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('newsevents'),
            Meteor.subscribe('images'),
            Meteor.subscribe('categories'),
            Meteor.subscribe('tags'),
        ]
    },
    data: function(){
    return NewsEvents.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },
});
```

The admin route (a form page) for adding a new entry:

```
// Admin news
Router.route('/admin-news-events', {
    name: 'adminNewsEvents',
    waitOn: function(){
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('newsevents'),
            Meteor.subscribe('images'),

        ]
    },
    data: function(){
        return false
    },
});
```

After submitting the post to the collection, I tried to catch the entry and pass the id, but I just get undefined.

My admin template.js (*edited*):

```
'submit form': function (evt, template) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var temp = {};
    temp.title = $('#title').val();
    temp.description = $('#description').summernote('code');
    temp.type = $('input[name=netype]:checked').val();
    temp.createdAt = moment().format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss ZZ');

    Meteor.call('NewsEvents.insert', temp);
    Bert.alert("New entry added.");

    //Fire the email to all Subscribers
    var entry = NewsEvents.findOne(this._id);
    var entryId = entry.id;

    //NOT WORKING
    var news = '<a href='+Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'news-and-events/'+entryId+'></a>';

    for (i = 0; i < Subscribers.find().count(); i++) {
    var email_ = Subscribers.find().fetch()[i].email;
      Meteor.call('sendEmail',
      email_, //To
      'Open Strategy Network <xxx.yyy@zzz.yyy.xx>', //from
      'Open Strategy Network News and Events', //subject
       news);
    }
  }
```

Server methods:

```
   Meteor.methods({
      'NewsEvents.insert': function (doc) {
        if (this.userId) {
          NewsEvents.insert(doc);
        }
      }
     });

...
//Send emails
    'sendEmail': function (to, from, subject, text) {
      // check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);
      this.unblock();
      Email.send({
        to: to,
        from: from,
        subject: subject,
        html: text
      });
    },
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` returns a cursor, not an object. You can either do:

```
var entry = NewsEvents.findOne(this._id);
var entryId = entry.id;
```

Or more simply since you already have the `_id`:

```
var entryId = this._id;
```

Or even more simply:

```
var news = '<a style:"text-decoration: none;"
  href='Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'news-and-events/'+this._id+'></a>';
```

Also, you are trying to send the email while your insert is happening asynchronously.

```
Meteor.call('NewsEvents.insert', temp); // this might take some time to complete

var entry = NewsEvents.findOne(this._id); // `this` is not going to refer to the just added NewsEvent
```

Instead, do the notifications in a callback from the method:

```
Meteor.call('NewsEvents.insert', temp, function(err, result){
  if ( !err ){

  // assuming that `result` will be the _id of the inserted object!!
    var news = '<a href='+Meteor.absoluteUrl()+'news-and-events/'+result+'></a>';

    Subscribers.find().forEach(function(s){
      Meteor.call('sendEmail',
        s.email, //To
        'Open Strategy Network <violetta.splitter@business.uzh.ch>', //from
        'Open Strategy Network News and Events', //subject
         news
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Your `NewsEvents.insert` method needs to return the `_id` of the inserted object:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'NewsEvents.insert'(doc) {
    if (this.userId) return NewsEvents.insert(doc);
   }
 });
```

Now, even the above will be slow since you're doing `Meteor.call()` in a loop. Secondly, you've opened up your server as a mail relay since anyone can use the `sendEmail` method to send any email to anyone from the console inside your app. If you want to do this efficiently, put the notification code inside your `NewsEvents.insert` method and do it all on the server without all the back and forth!!

Comment: Thank you. The solutions prints ... ```news-and-events/undefined```. This code is run AFTER inserting the new document into the collection but in the same submit form event. Any ideas why it's undefined? I edit my template.js file.

Comment: Can you show the code where you insert and then try to get the `_id`?

Comment: Looks great. I'll try it again, tomorrow. Currently   ```Meteor.call('NewsEvents.insert', temp, function (err, result) {
        if(!err) {
          console.log("result: " + result);
        }
        else {
          console.log("err: " + err);
        }
      });``` 
doesn't do anything. I wonder why. I edited my post again to add my methods.

Comment: the ```return NewsEvents.insert(doc)``` seems not to be enough? I separated this issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292221/meteor-callback-in-client-always-returns-undefined

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to have ID of the inserted document. Its fairly simple.

In the method that inserts:

```
var docId = Somethings.insert({ //fields here });
```

Now you can use that docId in the same method for sending emails.

If you also want to send the documentId to the client side, you can use error, result in `Meteor.call()` like this:

```
Meteor.call('methodName', arg, arg2, function(err, res){
    if(!err){
        //do something with res. in this case the res is inserted docId as I returned docId in the method
        Router.go('/some-route/' + docId)
    } else {
        //do something with err
    }
});
```

The error above comes from errors you throw in methods. For the result, you need to return a value which can be the inserted docId:

```
return docId
```

Tidied up method:

```
methodName: function (arg, arg2){
    //equals to err in the `Meteor.call()`
    if(arg !== 'something'){
        throw new Meteor.Error('This is an error')
    }

    //insert new document
    var docId = Somethings.insert({
        fieldOne: arg,
        fieldTwo: arg2
    });

    //send email to each subscriber. I don't know your exact DB fields so, its up to you. You did this in a different call.
    var cursor = Subscribers.find();
    cursor.forEach(function(ss){
        //send email here. You can use each subscriber data like ss._id or ss.email. However you insert them...
    });


    //Equals to res in `Meteor.call()`. sends a result to the client side method call. inserted docId in this case
    return docId
},
```

PS: If this doesn't answer you question, that means I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve exactly. Leave me a comment and I'll edit the answer.

**EDIT**

I used one method for both sending emails and inserting the document but still, you can pass error/result exactly like how I did and then do another call for emails using the id in result.

Comment: Thanks, before I can continue here, I wonder I get undefined in my callback

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38292221/meteor-callback-in-client-always-returns-undefined