# Meteor: callback in client always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Probably a very basic mistake but I can't find it:

Method in lib/collection.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'NewsEvents.insert': function (doc) {
    if (this.userId) {
      console.log(doc);
      return NewsEvents.insert(doc);
    }
  }, //...
```

Template in client folder:

```
Meteor.call('NewsEvents.insert', temp, function (err, result) {
        if(!err) {
          console.log("result: " + result);
        }
        else {
          console.log("err: " + err);
        }
  });
```

After inserting a document (works fine!), the console first prints the whole object (directy from the method),then in the next line:

`result: undefined`

Edit:
I also tried this method, it's the same issue:

```
'NewsEvents.insert': function (doc) {
    if (this.userId) {
      var docObject = NewsEvents.insert(doc);
      console.log("docObject: "  + docObject);
      return docObject;
    }
  }
```

Even without the `if`, it doesn't work:

```
'NewsEvents.insert': function (doc) {
    var docObject = NewsEvents.insert(doc);
    console.log("docObject: "  + docObject);
    return docObject;
  }
```

The result is:

`docObject: ac2vZkPueChM5rsSB` and next line:
`result: undefined`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the caller logged in?

Comment: Yes (and an admin). ```Meteor.userId()```prints the user id into the console.

Comment: Have you tried using `Meteor.userId()` instead of `this.userId`?

Comment: @Tobold: just tried. doesn't work. even if I delete the entire ```if```, I still get ```result: undefined```. :(

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Weird.